# Check if object has been synced to the Realm Object Server

Tags: swift, realm, realm-object-server

Is there  a way to check if the new object/edited object has been synced yet? I need to put an indicator that shows if the edited object has been successfully synced or is still only saved locally. I'm using Realm Object Server v1.0.

Comment: This in no way answers your question, but I'd strongly suggest you update to Realm Object Server v2.x. v1.x is no longer supported or actively maintained.

Comment: I was intending on upgrading once the digitalocean issues are resolved... I heard the 5$ server has issues with the new version... also I couldn't find the requested feature in the new version...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information isn't available at an object level granularity due to the way that synchronization works. Synchronization processes transactions at a time. You can use [`SyncSession.addProgressNotification(for:mode:block:)`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Extensions/SyncSession.html#/s:FE10RealmSwiftCSo14RLMSyncSession23addProgressNotificationFT3forOES_S0_17ProgressDirection4modeOES_S0_12ProgressMode5blockFVES_S0_8ProgressT__GSqCSo28RLMProgressNotificationToken_) with the `forCurrentlyOutstandingWork` progress mode to be notified when the changes made in a given write transaction have been uploaded.